# How to make custom buttons with different color?

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">   
     <gradient android:startColor="#4CC417" android:endColor="#7C4124" android:angle="270"/>   
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>   
 </shape>
```

This is my custom button xml. I want to modify the code to get two or more colors.

Comment: My question is... how do you reference this button.xml?

Answer (score 2):

A gradient from `startColor` to `endColor` already gives 2 colors. A center color can be added by using `android:centerColor="#hexcode"`.